# How to get Interface implemented from Annotation

Tags: java

I am using guice for dependency injection in my project. I have a few interfaces for which I have default bindings.

I want to provide the facility where the user can implement the interface and that custom implementation would be binded over default one. If no custom implementation is present Default binding should happen.

How can this be done?
I thought of a way where the user annotates the implemented classes with an annotation and I can get the interface from that and bind that class to that interface. Is this possible?

Please help.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

when you use spring framework, you can use declare a bean with `@ConditionalOnMissingBean`, if not, you can try to implement like this(check whether the object has bean declared)

Comment: Can you expand "check whether the object has bean declared"

Comment: such as: if not registry.containBean(A.class) :  new A()

Answer (score 0):

Probably best would be to have a BeanFactory, and the user should then provide his implementation for a given interface:

```
class BeanFactory {
    private static final Map<Class<?>, ?> beans = new HashMap<>();

    public static <T> void register(Class<T> type, T impl){
        beans.put(type, impl);
    }
}
```

That way you could have your beans initially declared in above factory and then they could get overwritten by a user.

```
class MyImpl implements MyService{
    static{
        BeanFactory.register(MyService.class, new MyImpl());
    }

    // Rest of code
}
```

Comment: I want to do the same myself instead of the user. Can I get the same details using an annotation?

Comment: @PardhaSaradi sadly, java doesn't know what classes are available at runtime, either you use a manual registry like above, or have to depend on a third party library, which scanns packages and classes, which then let's you allow to find them via annotations

Answer (score 0):

also, you can use SPI

```
    ServiceLoader<SayHello> services = ServiceLoader.load(SayHello.class);
```

if `services` is empty, you can new the default instance.